# Postgres replication multiple standby's

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using Postgres with one Primary and one standby, along with repmgr for automatic failover.

I am now required to add another standby on a **remote** site in case the local site goes down -  with the Primary and standby on it.

I saw that in case I add just 1 standby to the remote site, and the Primary and standby on the local site are stopped, then the standby on the remote site crashes too. The log shows that it looks for" the primary address, and as it cannot find it, it crashes.

When I added 2 more standby's on the remote site, then faiover occured, and one of the standby's indeed became a Primary.

My set up is then:
p  - Primary on local
s1 - standby on local
s2 - standby on remote
s3 - standby on remote
s4 - standby on remote

My questions are then:

1. In case I keep the "synchronous_commit" parameter on its default, which is "on", should I set the parameter "synchronous_standby_names" to ensure data consistency to the remote standby's?
   If so - which is best:
   synchronous_standby_names = 'ANY 2 (s1,s2)'
   Or
   synchronous_standby_names = 'FIRST 1 (s2,s3,s4)'
2. Should I use an odd number for the replicaset? or can I use only 2 standby's on the remote site, like tnis:
   p - Primary on local
   s1 - standby on local
   s2 - standby on remote
   s3 - standby on remote

Comment: Please show the actual error message, not a paraphrasing of it.  And what does 'crash' mean to you?

Comment: Log shows that it tries to connect to what was Primary up to this point, but the connection is refused:
[38;5;6mpostgresql-repmgr[38;5;5m14:24:35.19[0m[38;5;5mDEBUG[0m ==> Host '1.9.7.17:5065' is not accessible